# woocommerce, Hide those product on Website that are in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to Wordpress. I am developing store by using Woocommerce. When a product is added to cart then they must be hidden on the website for a specific time so that those products that are in the cart by any other user, not available on the website.

How can I do this?

I searched a lot but found nothing.

Comment: This is not a common requirement and most probably has to be implemented by yourself. Please be aware, that this might introduce serious privacy problems if not done right, since you will have to collect the cart contents from each user currently visiting your site and such information is usually stored in the PHP sessions. You should also keep in mind, that a product is at least blocked for the lifetime of the session. You can see, there a lot of things to care of and I didn't even started to think about the implementation. As it is, this question is much too broad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove add to cart button from the products which are already in cart then you will need to check for the products' ID from the woocommerce cart session. and then use the filter hook woocommerce_is_purchasable.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'coder_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2);
function coder_woocommerce_is_purchasable($is_purchasable, $product) {
        return ($product->id == cart_session_product_id ? false : $is_purchasable);
}
```

In this way, you can hide the add to cart button.

If you want to hide the product itself then in woocommerce product loop in shop page, Just compare the product id from the woocommerce session cart and traverse the loop. If ID matches then skip that product. Customize this products loop of shop page in woocommerce theme template.